# Resulting array is zero when jax.numpy is used

Tags: python, numpy, jax

I wrote the code below using numpy and got the correct output as shown in program 1. However when I switch to jax.numpy as jnp (in Program 2) the resulting output is an array of zeros. My MWE is shown below. I would like to know where I got the computation wrong?
PS: the codes were run in different python files.

```
#Program 1 (using numpy as np):
import numpy as np

num_rows = 5
num_cols = 20
smf = np.array([np.inf, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1])
par_init = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])
lb = np.array([0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1])
ub = np.array([10, 10, 10, 10, 10])
par = np.broadcast_to(par_init[:,None],(num_rows,num_cols))

kvals = np.where(np.isinf(smf), 1, num_cols)
kvals = np.insert(kvals, 0, 0)
kvals = np.cumsum(kvals)

par0_col = np.zeros(num_rows*num_cols - (num_cols-1) * np.sum(np.isinf(smf)))
lb_col = np.zeros(num_rows*num_cols - (num_cols-1) * np.sum(np.isinf(smf)))
ub_col = np.zeros(num_rows*num_cols- (num_cols-1) * np.sum(np.isinf(smf)))



for i in range(num_rows):
    par0_col[kvals[i]:kvals[i+1]] = par[i, :kvals[i+1]-kvals[i]]
    lb_col[kvals[i]:kvals[i+1]] = lb[i]
    ub_col[kvals[i]:kvals[i+1]] = ub[i]

arr_1 = np.zeros(shape = (num_rows, num_cols))
arr_2 = np.zeros(shape = (num_rows, num_cols))


par_log = np.log10((par0_col - lb_col) / (1 - par0_col / ub_col))


k = 0
for i in range(num_rows):

    arr_1[i, :] = (par_log[kvals[i]:kvals[i+1]])
    arr_2[i, :] = 10**par_log[kvals[i]:kvals[i+1]]
  

print(arr_1)

# [[0.         0.         0.         0.         0.         0.
#   0.         0.         0.         0.         0.         0.
#   0.         0.         0.         0.         0.         0.
#   0.         0.        ]
#  [0.37566361 0.37566361 0.37566361 0.37566361 0.37566361 0.37566361
#   0.37566361 0.37566361 0.37566361 0.37566361 0.37566361 0.37566361
#   0.37566361 0.37566361 0.37566361 0.37566361 0.37566361 0.37566361
#   0.37566361 0.37566361]
#  [0.61729996 0.61729996 0.61729996 0.61729996 0.61729996 0.61729996
#   0.61729996 0.61729996 0.61729996 0.61729996 0.61729996 0.61729996
#   0.61729996 0.61729996 0.61729996 0.61729996 0.61729996 0.61729996
#   0.61729996 0.61729996]
#  [0.81291336 0.81291336 0.81291336 0.81291336 0.81291336 0.81291336
#   0.81291336 0.81291336 0.81291336 0.81291336 0.81291336 0.81291336
#   0.81291336 0.81291336 0.81291336 0.81291336 0.81291336 0.81291336
#   0.81291336 0.81291336]
#  [0.99122608 0.99122608 0.99122608 0.99122608 0.99122608 0.99122608
#   0.99122608 0.99122608 0.99122608 0.99122608 0.99122608 0.99122608
#   0.99122608 0.99122608 0.99122608 0.99122608 0.99122608 0.99122608
#   0.99122608 0.99122608]]

# Program 2 (using jax.numpy as jnp):

import jax
import jax.numpy as jnp
jax.config.update("jax_enable_x64", True)

smf = jnp.array([jnp.inf, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1])
par_init = jnp.array([1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0,5.0])
lb = jnp.array([0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1])
ub = jnp.array([10.0, 10.0, 10.0, 10.0, 10.0])
par = jnp.broadcast_to(par_init[:,None],(num_rows,num_cols))

kvals = jnp.where(jnp.isinf(smf), 1, num_cols)
kvals = jnp.insert(kvals, 0, 0)
kvals = jnp.cumsum(kvals)

par0_col = jnp.zeros(num_rows*num_cols - (num_cols-1) * jnp.sum(jnp.isinf(smf)))
lb_col = jnp.zeros(num_rows*num_cols - (num_cols-1) * jnp.sum(jnp.isinf(smf)))
ub_col = jnp.zeros(num_rows*num_cols- (num_cols-1) * jnp.sum(jnp.isinf(smf)))



for i in range(num_rows):
    par0_col.at[kvals[i]:kvals[i+1]].set(par[i, :kvals[i+1]-kvals[i]])
    lb_col.at[kvals[i]:kvals[i+1]].set(lb[i])
    ub_col.at[kvals[i]:kvals[i+1]].set(ub[i])

arr_1 = jnp.zeros(shape = (num_rows, num_cols))
arr_2 = jnp.zeros(shape = (num_rows, num_cols))


par_log = jnp.log10((par0_col - lb_col) / (1 - par0_col / ub_col))


for i in range(num_rows):
 
    arr_1.at[i, :].set((par_log[kvals[i]:kvals[i+1]]))
    arr_2.at[i, :].set(10**par_log[kvals[i]:kvals[i+1]])
  

print(arr_1)

# #[[0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
#  [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
#  [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
#  [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
#  [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that [`ndarray.at` expressions](https://jax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_autosummary/jax.numpy.ndarray.at.html#jax.numpy.ndarray.at) don't operate in-place, but rather return a modified value.

So instead of this:

```
arr_1.at[i, :].set((par_log[kvals[i]:kvals[i+1]]))
arr_2.at[i, :].set(10**par_log[kvals[i]:kvals[i+1]])
```

You should write this:

```
arr_1 = arr_1.at[i, :].set((par_log[kvals[i]:kvals[i+1]]))
arr_2 = arr_2.at[i, :].set(10**par_log[kvals[i]:kvals[i+1]])
```

Read more at [JAX sharp bits: in-place updates](https://jax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/notebooks/Common_Gotchas_in_JAX.html#in-place-updates).

Answer (score 0):

Oh I already figured it out. I needed to make an explicit assignment.